# Update DB::table from passed object of array in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, laravel

In laravel, I'm trying to update several tables and rows. i have items that are to be received and checked by 2 different users.

in my show.blade.php, i have this verify button and submit button depending on the user.

```
@if (($current_user_id  != $saved_receiver_id) && ($saved_receiver_id != $not_yet_received))    

    <div class="row padder m-b">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="received_by" class="pull-left" >Received by:</label> <span class="fa"></span>
            <input type="hidden" name="receiver_id" value="{{ $saved_receiver_id }}" >{{ $receiver_username }}</input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row padder m-b">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="received_date" class="pull-left" >Received date:</label> <span class="fa"></span>
            <input type="hidden" name="received_date" value="{{ $received_date }}" >{{ $received_date }}</input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="purchase_orders_id" value="{{ $purchase_order_number }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="checker_id" value="{{ $current_user_id }}">
    <div class="row padder m-b">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="final_checker_remarks" class="pull-left" >Final Remarks</label>
            <textarea class="form-control col-md-12" name="final_checker_remarks" value="{{ $final_checker_remarks }}" id="final_checker_remarks">{{ $final_checker_remarks }}</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-success btn-sm submit-btn" id="update-form-submit" data-action="verified">Verified</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    @else
    <div class="pull-right">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm submit-btn" id="update-form-submit" data-action="submit">Submit List</button>
        </a>
    </div>
@endif
```

now in my ReceivesController.php, i have this postUpdate function,

```
public function postUpdate(Request $request)
{
    if (! $request->ajax()) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $items = json_decode($request->items);
    $action = json_decode($request->action);        
    if(!count($items) && !count($items->purchase_item_id)){
        return false;
    }

    $cnt = count($items->purchase_item_id);     
// Receiver Submit function 
    if ($action == "submit") {

// Saves the received id of the one who received to purchase order table        
        DB::table('purchase_orders')
        ->where('id', $items->purchase_orders_id)
        ->update([
            'receiver_id'       =>  $items->receiver_id,

        ]);


// Saves the quantity received and receiver remarks to purchase items table 
        for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++){
            DB::table('purchase_items')
            ->where('id', $items->purchase_item_id[$i])
            ->update([
                    'quantity_received' =>  $items->quantity_received[$i], 
                    'receiver_remarks'  =>  $items->receiver_remarks[$i],
                ]);
        }   
// Items Received Success Message           
        $message = 'Items Received';
    } 
// QA or Checker Finalize function  
    else {

// Saves the checker id, and final checker remarks of the one who made the QA to purchase order table   
        DB::table('purchase_orders')
        ->where('id', $items->purchase_orders_id)
        ->update([
            'checker_id'            =>  $items->checker_id,
            'final_checker_remarks' =>  $items->final_checker_remarks,
        ]);
// Saves the quality received and checker remarks to purchase items table   
for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++){                       

            $quality_received = $items->quality_received;
            if(is_array($items->quality_received)){
                $quality_received = $items->quality_received[$i];
            }

            $checker_remarks = $items->checker_remarks;
            if(is_array($items->checker_remarks)){
                $checker_remarks = $items->checker_remarks[$i];
            }

            $quantity_received = $items->quantity_received;
            if(is_array($items->quantity_received)){
                $quantity_received = $items->quantity_received[$i];
            }

            $receiver_remarks = $items->receiver_remarks;
            if(is_array($items->receiver_remarks)){
                $receiver_remarks = $items->receiver_remarks[$i];
            }


            DB::table('purchase_items')
            ->where('id', $items->purchase_item_id[$i])
            ->update([
                    'quality_received'  =>  $quality_received, 
                    'checker_remarks'   =>  $checker_remarks,                       
                    'quantity_received' =>  $quantity_received, 
                    'receiver_remarks'  =>  $receiver_remarks,
                ]);
// Increments or Adds the quantity received to items table  
            DB::table('items')
            ->where('purchase_items.id', $items->purchase_item_id[$i])
            ->join('purchase_items', 'items.id', '=', 'purchase_items.item_id')
            ->increment('items.measurement', $items->quantity_received[$i]);

        }
/   / Items Finalized Success Message       
        $message = 'Items Verified';
    }
// Returns Success Message 
    return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => $message
        ]);
}
```

Now my problem is only the first letter of the word that is typed in the input area are being saved, and in others they are not saved, however, in other, it can be saved. I know its weird, but i cant find which part of my codes is doing such result, what is it that i need to do for me to update my tables correctly? Thanks in advance for the help.

Update: Here is my receive-form-function.js

```
    /* ========================================================================
 *  Initialize Pages
 * ======================================================================== */
    $(initialPages);

/* ========================================================================
 *  Major function
 * ======================================================================== */

/* ==== function to init this page === */
function initialPages($) {

    // if($('#receives-list-table').length){
    //  DataTables("#receives-list-table", "receives");
    // }

    if($('#receiveItems-list-table').length){
            $("#receiveItems-list-table").DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            ordering: false,
        });
    }

    $('#update-form-submit').on('click', function(){
        var action = $(this).data('action');
        updateReceiveItem(action);
    });
    clearInputs();
}

/* === dataTables === */
function DataTables(selector, controller) {
    $(selector).DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: url+'/'+controller+'/paginate'
    });
}

function updateReceiveItem(action){
    loadingModal('show','Updating ....');
    ajaxCsrfToken();

    var data = $('#receiveItems_id').serializeArray();
        data = JSON.stringify(data);
        // data = JSON.parse(data);
        data = JSON.stringify($('#receiveItems_id').serializeObject());
        // data = $('#receiveItems_id').serializeObject();

    $.ajax({
            url: url+'/receives/update',
            type: 'post',
            data: {'items':data, 'action': action},
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: function() {      
                loadingModal('close');
            },
            error: function(result) {

            },
            success: function(result) {

                successAlert('#receiveItems-result', result.message);
            // if (result.success) {

            //      $('input, select, textarea').attr('disabled', true);

            //  } else {
            //      alert(result.message);
            //  }
            }

        });
        console.log(data);
        return false;
}
/**
 * Use to format serialize data and convert to json data
 *
 * Usage: JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject())
 */
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = Object.create(null),
        elementMapper = function(element) {
            element.name = $.camelCase(element.name);
            return element;
        },
        appendToResult = function(i, element) {
            var node = o[element.name];

            if ('undefined' != typeof node && node !== null) {
                o[element.name] = node.push ? node.push(element.value) : [node, element.value];
            } else {
                o[element.name] = element.value;
            }
        };

    $.each($.map(this.serializeArray(), elementMapper), appendToResult);
    console.log(o);
    return o;
};
```

Comment: for all those rows that were chosen to be updated.

Comment: what are you getting when u dump simple value?

Comment: when i enter a word in an input, for example: hello
the only one saved in the table is letter h.

Comment: once $items = json_decode($request->items); response back before saving to the database and see what are you gettin

Comment: now, when i have 3 rows being updated, it doesnt work anymore. im getting this error: 

**QueryException in Connection.php line 636:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where `purchase_items`.`id` is null' at line 1 (SQL: update `items` inner join `purchase_items` on `items`.`id` = `purchase_items`.`item_id` set `items`.`measurement` = `items`.`measurement` + where `purchase_items`.`id` is null)**

Comment: i tried calling out $items = json_decode($request->items); in message field, it is giving me 
[object Object]

Comment: here is what i get from console.log
{"receiveItemsListTable_length":"10","purchase_item_id":3,"quantity_received":3,"receiver_remarks":3,"quality_received":3,"checker_remarks":3,"receiver_id":"16","received_date":"2016-02-04 17:41:06","purchase_orders_id":"16","checker_id":"6","final_checker_remarks":"kkkkkkkkkkk"}

Comment: the data ur getting is correct and it should insert

Comment: it's not updating :(

Comment: @ujwal dhakal 
what i need to pass is something like this.
**{"receiveItemsListTable_length":"10","purchase_item_id":["1","2"],"quantity_received":["10","1"],"receiver_remarks":["mmmmmmmmn","llllllll"],"quality_received":["nnnnnnnnn","cccccccccc"],"checker_remarks":["bbbbbb","mmmmmmmmmm"],"receiver_id":"6","received_date":"2016-02-05 11:49:24","purchase_orders_id":"2","checker_id":"16","final_checker_remarks":"bbbbbbbbbbbbb"}**
how can i do this?

Comment: You mean insert json value ? or one by one filtering?

Comment: one by one filtering boss. 
i have a hunch that this function in my js is the one in-charge of it, i just don't know how it does it. 
i will update my post and show you  my receiver-form-function.js

Comment: @ujwal dhakal 
i updated my post to show you my receiver-form-function.js

Comment: I will tel you to debug first test whether the value is being displayed or not next if its displayed on controller and next is on controller try inserting same data be careful you need to define fillable

Comment: @ujwal dhakal
the weird thing is that when i have 2 items, it produces an array per value, which is the one that i need to update the table, 

**{"receiveItemsListTable_length":"10","purchase_item_id":["1","2"],"quantity_rec‌​eived":["10","1"],"receiver_remarks":["mmmmmmmmn","llllllll"],"quality_received":‌​["nnnnnnnnn","cccccccccc"],"checker_remarks":["bbbbbb","mmmmmmmmmm"],"receiver_id‌​":"6","received_date":"2016-02-05 11:49:24","purchase_orders_id":"2","checker_id":"16","final_checker_remarks":"bb‌​bbbbbbbbbbb"}**

but when i already have three items, it counts the items. =(

Comment: here is what it passes when i have 3 items 

**{"receiveItemsListTable_length":"10","purchase_item_id":3,"quantity_received":3,"receiver_remarks":3,"quality_received":3,"checker_remarks":3,"receiver_id":"16","received_date":"2016-02-05 14:26:00","purchase_orders_id":"3","checker_id":"6","final_checker_remarks":"jjjjjjjjjjj"}**

Comment: now select single item from it and try checking whether u get value or not and then save

Comment: for a single item, here is what it passes

**{"receiveItemsListTable_length":"10","purchase_item_id":"6","quantity_received":"2","receiver_remarks":"","quality_received":"wwww","checker_remarks":"eeeeeeee","receiver_id":"6","received_date":"2016-02-05 15:34:19","purchase_orders_id":"6","checker_id":"16","final_checker_remarks":"rrrrrrrrr"}**

Comment: @ujwal dhakal i found the bug, the $.fn.serializeObject = function() that i am using above is giving me different json objects. i found a different code for serializeObject and i tried it , and it worked. it now gives me the correct format. thanks for the patience with me =)

Answer (score 1):

my $.fn.serializeObject = function() above seems to have the bug, i tried using another $.fn.serializeObject = function(), and it gave me the json object that i want. here is the $.fn.serializeObject = function() that i am using now.

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```